# If $\nabla f(x)^T (x^{*}-x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in C$ then $x^{*}$ is optimal solution of CP

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

The question is suppose that $f(x)$ is convex over a closed and convex set $C$. Show that $x^{*}\in C$ is optimal solution of $\min\{f(x): x\in C\}$ if $\nabla f(x)^T (x^{*}-x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in C$.

I have to show that

I wrote this:

$\nabla f(x)^T (x^{*}-x) \leq 0 \Rightarrow f'(x; x^*-x) \leq 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+t(x^*-x))-f(x)}{t}\leq 0 \Rightarrow \exists \delta \\ \forall t\in(0,\delta): \ f(x+t(x^*-x))-f(x)\leq 0$

But I don't think it would work! Would you please give me a hand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\nabla f(x^*)^T(x-x^*)\ge0 \quad \forall x$ implies global minimum at $x^*$ for a convex function on a convex set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546810/nabla-fxtx-x-ge0-quad-forall-x-implies-global-minimum-at-x-for)

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen No it's different from that. :(

Comment: hm. Isn't it the same? Can you tell me why they're diiferent?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen In my question is $\nabla f(x)$ for any $x$ but in that question it's $\nabla f(x^*)$

Comment: Oh, interesting.

Comment: The intuitive idea is that if $x \in C$ then the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v = x - x^*$ can't be negative. If it were negative, then $x^*$ would not be a minimizer, because starting from $x^*$ we could reduce the value of $f$ by moving a bit in the direction $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $x \in C$, let $v=x-x^*$.
Consider $g(t)= f(x^*+tv)$ on $[0,1]$, we see that for all $t \in (0,1)$ :
$$g'(t)=\langle \nabla f(x^*+tv), v \rangle =\frac{1}{t}\left\langle \nabla f(x^*+tv), (x^*+tv)-x^* \right\rangle \stackrel{\text{Hypothesis}}{\ge} 0 $$
Thus $g$ is increasing on $[0,1]$, that means $g(0) \le g(1)$ or
$$f(x^*) \le f(x)$$

---

**P.s**: So the convexity is superfluous.

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks.

Comment: "the convexity is superfluous" We at least need $C$ to be convex, right?

Comment: @littleO Indeed. I was just talking about the function.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is question 9.1 of Amir Beck's book on Nonlinear Optimization. I assume the opposite direction has been shown, as it is easy to deduce from the monotonicity of the gradient. My proof goes as follows:

Assume $x^*$ is not an optimal solution, i.e. $\exists x^{**}\in X$ that is an optimal solution and $x^{**}\neq x^*$ (existence is trivial due to this being a convex problem). Then by the first-order definition of stationarity, $x^{**}$ satisfies:
$$
\nabla f(x^{**})^\top(x-x^{**}) \geq 0
$$
By assumption, $x^*$ satisfies
$$
\nabla f(x)^\top(x^*-x) \leq 0
$$
for all $x\in X$. Now plug in $x=x^{**}$ into the second equation above to obtain
$$
\nabla f(x^{**})^\top(x^*-x^{**}) \leq 0
$$
and plugging in $x=x^*$ into the first equation in this text yields
$$
\nabla f(x^{**})^\top (x^*-x^{**})\geq 0
$$
so we conclude that
$$
\nabla f(x^{**})^\top (x^*-x^{**})= 0
$$

We now use the monotonicity of the gradient to deduce that
$$
(\nabla f(x^*) - \nabla f(x^{**}))^\top(x^*-x^{**}) \geq 0 \implies \nabla f(x^*)^\top (x^*-x^{**})\geq 0
$$
which in turn implies
$$
\nabla f(x^*)^\top (x^*-x^{**})= 0
$$

Hence $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$, showing $x^*$ is stationary (as $x^* \neq x^{**}$), contradicting our initial assumption.